# Step Down Layout with CSS

Tags: css

Does anyone has any idea how to make this layout with CSS? If CSS is not possible, any other method is okay too.

[layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU5jR.jpg)

Code below, this is in a while loop.

```
<div class="work-column">
                <div class="featured-work" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');">
                    <div class="work-content">
                        <div class="top">
                            <div class="top-row">
                                <div class="top-cell"><?php echo $num_padded; ?></div>
                                <div class="top-cell"><?php the_field('category'); ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="middle">
                            <div class="short-description"><?php the_field('short_description'); ?></div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('view_case_study_link_text'); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <div class="work-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                            <div class="services"><?php the_field('services'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /featured-work -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the :nth-child(3n+3) css3 selector to select one div every three!

the code will look like:

```
div.work-column:nth-child(3n+2) {
  transform:translateY(33%);
}
div.work-column:nth-child(3n+3) {
  transform:translateY(66%);
}
```

```css
div.work {
  width:600px;
}

div.work-column {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 0 -4px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: #666 dotted 2px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.work-column:nth-child(3n+2) {
  transform:translateY(33%);
}
div.work-column:nth-child(3n+3) {
  transform:translateY(66%);
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <div class="work-column">
  </div><div class="work-column">
  </div><div class="work-column">
  </div><div class="work-column">
  </div><div class="work-column">
  </div><div class="work-column">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I just tried your method, it works but I see that I have to add width to ''work" and "work-column", is there any way I can make it full screen width?

Comment: I just find out how to do that, lol, you method works great. Thank you!

Comment: you can use proportional measures (100%, 33.33%) instead of pixels. Another advice is not to put spaces between </ div> and <div> otherwise objects will not align as you want. cheers!